# how to integrate UINavigation bar with UIBarbuttonitem?

Tags: iphone

here is my code....?how to integrate UINavigation bar with UIBarbuttonitem?

```
UINavigationBar *nav= [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
nav.backgroundColor = [UIColor whitecolor];
//nav.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[self.view addSubview:nav];
[nav release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try init your item and then

```
nav.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

or

```
nav.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

You can only have two items on the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Note that UIBarButtonItem buttons are properties of the **UINavigationItem**, not the **UINavigationBar**.

For example, when using a UINavigationController, it automatically provides its own UINavigationBar. But each of the views managed by the navigation controller can define a UINavigationItem, which controls the title, left and right buttons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Update: iOS 5 supports multiple buttons on the same side. From the **UINavigationItem** docs:

Customizing Views

```
  titleView  property
  leftBarButtonItems  property
  leftBarButtonItem  property
  rightBarButtonItems  property
  rightBarButtonItem  property
– setLeftBarButtonItems:animated:
– setLeftBarButtonItem:animated:
– setRightBarButtonItems:animated:
– setRightBarButtonItem:animated:
```

So, basically, you would write something like this to add two buttons on the left:

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshPlans:)];
UIBarButtonItem *selectYearBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Year" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(selectYear)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: refreshBtn, selectYearBtn, nil];
```

Unfortunately, I haven't seen a way to do this in the Storyboard. Hope this helps.